# .agg Sum Converting NaN to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to bin a Pandas DataFrame into three day windows. I have two columns, A and B, which I want to sum in each window. This code which I wrote for the task

```
    df = df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg({'A': 'sum', 'B':'sum'})
```

Converts NaN values to zero when doing this sum, but I would like them to remain NaN as my data has actual non-NaN zero values.

For example if I had this df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
     [np.nan, np.nan],
     [np.nan, 0],
     [np.nan, np.nan],
     [2,   0],
     [4 ,  0],
     [0  , 0]
], columns=['A','B'])

Index A   B
0     NaN Nan
1     NaN 3
2     NaN Nan
3     2   0
4     4   0
5     0   0
```

I would like the new df to be:

```
Index A   B
0     NaN 3
1     6   0
```

But my current code outputs:

```
Index A   B
0     0   3
1     6   0
```

Comment: You need the min_count parameter. If you are only taking sum, this is the most straightforward way: `df.groupby(df.index // 3)['A', 'B'].sum(min_count=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby(df.index // 3)['A', 'B'].mean()
```

The above snippet provides the mentioned sample output.

If you want to go for the sum, look at `df.groupby(df.index // 3)['A', 'B'].sum(min_count = 1)`

**Another option:**

```
df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg({'A': lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False),
                           'B':lambda x: x.sum(skipna=True)})
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was wrong. I do in fact want the sum.

Comment: Guessed so. Updated my answer.

Comment: How could I adapt your first solution if I want to add third column with mean computed instead?

Comment: @taurus

df = pd.DataFrame([
     [np.nan, np.nan],
     [np.nan, 3],
     [np.nan, np.nan],
     [2,   0],
     [4 ,  0],
     [0  , 0]
], columns=['A','B'])


df['index'] = df.index//3


mean_df = df.groupby(df.index // 3)['A'].mean().reset_index().rename(columns = {'A': 'A_mean'})


df = df.merge(mean_df, on = 'index', how = 'left')

This will help calculate the mean of column 'A' and merge the mean with your df.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg({'A': lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False),
                               'B':lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False)})
Out[282]: 
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  6.0  0.0
```

Comment: check your output , first row second value should be 0 , your output is NaN

Comment: `skipna=False` will return `NaN` if any value is `NaN`. The question needs it only if _all_ values are `NaN`